# Angular2 error in getting JSON from external URL using JSONP

Tags: angular, jsonp

In `Angular2` I am making a get request to Indeed job search `API` to fetch jobs list but I am getting the following error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The code in my component is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'jobs.html'
})
export class JobsPage {

    constructor(
        private jsonp: Jsonp
    ) { }

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    ngOnInit() {

        this.jsonp.get('http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=<my_publisher_id>&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json', { headers: this.headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            (e) => { console.log(e); }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your expecting json but you want to make it jsonp , that won't work .

Comment: have you tried this ? 2&format=jsonp ????

Comment: I think you also need to change the content-type to this ": application/javascript

Comment: There only only two values for format i.e. `json` and `xml`

Comment: Not working with content-type application/javascript

Comment: You need to use `this.http.get` not `jsonp`.

Comment: Getting this error with http.get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=<id>&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP usually takes a `callback` parameter to point to a global method to execute the result, which should be a JavaScript script returned with `Content-Type: application/javascript`.

This isn't documented, but from the source code we infer that you'll need to add another parameter with a literal value:

```
&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK
```

Without this parameter, Indeed API returns `application/json`. Append it and you'll get `application/javascript`.

Also, remove the header `Content-Type` you're adding to the request, because sending no content don't call for it. This doesn't affect the response, only the way request is interpreted. (In time, no header is accepted for JSONP, no matter the implementation.)

Source: [jsonp_backend.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.ts)

**UPDATE:**

Because Angular Jsonp generates a compound name (`object.method`) for the callback, and we want to get things done, the solution is using a 3rd-party library to handle jsonp.

Here's a simple one: https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp

```
fetchJsonp('http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=<my_publisher_id>&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

Notice you can't send headers with JSONP. Angular's Jsonp is misleading on that. And you have a promise instead of an observable.

Comment: I have tried this but getting the same error. I have removed the headers content-type and added the callback variable to URL. Refused to execute script from 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=<id>&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: This URL returns `application/javascript`: http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5656845852938153&v=2&format=json&callback=jQuery1710167889759875834_1331926740707&q=&l=Madrid&sort=relevance&radius=25&st=jobsite&jt=fulltime&start=0&limit=4&fromage=10&fil. What's different from the URL you have?

Comment: It might be a bug. Angular uses `.` on the callback names, the api doesn't seem to accept: http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=%3Cid%3E&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json&callback=__ng_jsonp__

Comment: My URL is: `http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=<id>&q=java&l=austin&v=2&format=json&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`

Comment: There's an open issue. Is not your URL, but the modified URL Angular uses to make the request. Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13175

Comment: yes, use a third-party lib for jsonp. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Yes please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can I use it with Angular2 ?

Comment: load the script or install and add `import 'fetch-jsonp';` to your main.ts, it will add fetchJsonp to global scope. tsc will complain about it, `declare var fetchJsonp: any` wherever you use it or take a look how to properly declare symbols for tsc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129702/discussion-between-ali-shahzad-and-andre-werlang).